# ngCordova camera works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I'm building an app with Ionic for my Course Conclusion (I'm really in a hurry because I have only 2 weeks left) and I'm stuck with a ngCordova Camera Plugin issue.
When testing on the emulator the camera works fine, on my device no image appears. It doesn't show a cracked image icon either, just a blank square.
On the emulator I tried using 3 differents Android API versions: 17, 19 and 22 (and it works on all the 3), but on my device with a API 22 it doesn't work.

I'm using Genymotion emulator and **> ionic run android** and here is what I get:
[Emulator: Xperia Z - android 4.2.2 API 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNEMa.jpg)

But when I try **> ionic build android** and install it on my device, this is what I get:

[Device: Xperia Z2 - Android 5.1 API 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmjN9.jpg)

It's like this for all images on all pages, if I shot the picture or get it from library. Here's my code (from where the pictures came from):

form.html (it's a modal):

```
<div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
      <span class="input-label">Nome</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="nomeperfil">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
      <span class="input-label">Sobrenome</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome" ng-model="snperfil">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-block button-royal" ng-click="escolhefotoperfil()">Escolha uma foto para o perfil!</button>
    <img id="fotoperfil" class="picture" ng-model="fotoperfil" ng-show="fotoperfil !== undefined" ng-src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+fotoperfil}}"></img>
    <br /><br />
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="salvarUsuario(nomeperfil, snperfil, fotoperfil)">Salvar</button>
  </div>
```

My controller for the page were the modal is launched (just the camera part, if needed I'll add more code):

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $cordovaNetwork, $localStorage, $ionicPopup, $cordovaCamera, $state, $ionicPlatform, client) {
   $scope.escolhefotoperfil = function(){
   var options = {
     quality: 50,
     destinationType: 0,
     sourceType: 0,
     allowEdit: true,
     encodingType: 1,
     targetWidth: 300,
     targetHeight: 300,
     popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
     saveToPhotoAlbum: false
   };

   $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
      $scope.fotoperfil = imageData;
   }, function (err) {
     $scope.errofoto = "Erro ao escolher foto: " + err.message;
   });
 };
});
```

I've tried:

- Reinstall the plugin
- Reinstall platform
- Change *DATA_URL* to *FILE_URI*
- Taking out the *'data:image/jpeg;base64,'* from the *< img >* tag and using it on the function with *imageData*

Can someone help me out?

**EDIT:**

Using *Chrome Inspect* it shows the following error when trying to load an image:

***Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.*** on ionic.bundle.js:16438

Now i've add the **img-src 'self' *;** to my meta tag on my index, the error changed to:

***Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src *".***

Comment: Try debugging your app with [Chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) and check for errors in the console...

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the camera plugin?

Comment: @Phonolog i've done as you said and  it's giving this error: _Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback._ on **ionic.bundle.js**

Comment: i had the same issue on android 4.4, i created new project with cordova create command, earlier i did it with ionic start, then cordova build android pls try that, may solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change
img-src 'self' *;
to
img-src 'self' data:;
This should allow loading resources via the data scheme (eg Base64 encoded images).

Comment: This solved the problem for me, i was stuck even with Google Maps API imagens, now it's showing everything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) In your case the mistake i see is in this line

`$scope.fotoperfil = imageData;`  In **imageData** you have only base64 string so you can not able to vie in UI

It should be like this $scope.fotoperfil = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; here **data:image/jpeg;base64** this converts your base64 strings into .jpeg image.

2) You should have a place holder in your **img** tag to view the take pic.

3) Easy way to invoke camera follow Nic Raboy [blog](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/) here.

Change your html UI **img** tag into this

```
<img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
<img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
```

and add

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

in your html.

and change in your module like this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

based upon your need you can choose **DATA_URL** or **FILE_URI** according to this [ng-Cordova camera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) .